# Notebook display flickering, image stuck at screen even at booting?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I bought a **new notebook** a few weeks ago, and **yesterday this happened** as well, but **today not even a restart can fix it**:

When I'm in the **Operating System** it's **constantly flickering**, and when I **restart**, the image which is flickering is **already stuck in the screen** at **boot time**:
[image]

If I set the refresh rate from 48 HZ to 120Hz, it's no longer flickering, but the burnt in image is still frozen in the screen.

What should I do? Should I tell the retailer that I want new product?

Comment: When you buy new stuff and it fails soon, **always** exercise your right to have it replaced. Even if you could get it to work now, the problem may return later, when your warranty runs out.

Comment: I've just had something similar happen on my HP Spectre x360. Changing the refresh rate from 60Hz to 40Hz fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it replaced, and then it still happened.

I sent it back again, and as it turned out, the firmware was buggy, and it was needed to be updated.